# filter special characters from permalinks i.e domain.com/?p=c%3A%2F

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, theme-development

whenever I scan my website for security in OWASP ZAP it always show the high risk vulnerability of path traversal attack from certain urls i.e

```
domain.com/?p=c%3A%2F
domain.com/?post_type=c%3A%2F
domain.com/?s=c%3A%2F
```

How can I secure my website from these kind of path traversal attacks?

Comment: Are you _using_ these values in any file system or URL context? Otherwise, where is the path traversal possibility supposed to be here?

Comment: @CBroe No, The software I use to scan for security tells me that these kind of url context can cause path traversal attack. That's why I want to make them secure but don't understand how to do it. I've tried many things but didn't work.

Comment: _“Can”_ is the operative word here. If you do not _use_ these parameters in any “path context”, then there is no vector for attack here. _“That's why I want to make them secure but don't understand how to do it.”_ - you can not “secure” anything, if you have not even properly understood what the _issue_ is to begin with. So I would suggest you go read up on that _properly_ first of all now.